# Closing/reopening QML ApplicationWindow makes RotationAnimator go nuts

Tags: c++, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have a very weird behavior, that I have minimized to a minimal example and hope someone could have some knowledge about.

I have a QML `ApplicationWindow` that I occasionally want to show depending on a button being pressed or other stuff. The window contains an `Image` with `RotationAnimator` which works fine the first time the window becomes visible. However if I close it and reopen from some kind of event (e.g. system tray menu being clicked), the animation goes nuts and spins with a very fast speed. This happens only on Windows but works fine on Mac.

I've hosted a minimal example on https://github.com/rubu/QtRotationAnimatorDemo.

The relevant parts - qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1

ApplicationWindow
{
    id: window
    visible: true

    width : 400
    height : 400

    Connections
    {
        target: applicationContext

        onShowWindow:
        {
            window.show()
        }
    }

    Image
    {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        source: "./ring.png"
        RotationAnimator on rotation
         {
            id: rotationAnimation
            loops: Animation.Infinite
            duration: 2000
            from: 0 ; to: 360

            onRunningChanged:
            {
                console.log("animation running: " + rotationAnimation.running + " " + rotationAnimation.duration + " " + rotationAnimation.loops)
            }

            onPausedChanged:
            {
                console.log("animation paused: " + rotationAnimation.running + " " + rotationAnimation.duration  + " " + rotationAnimation.loops)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`main.cpp` -

```
#include "ApplicationContext.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QSystemTrayIcon>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication Application(argc, argv);
    QApplicationContext ApplicationContext;
    Application.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
    QSystemTrayIcon SystemTrayIcon;
    ApplicationContext.connect(&SystemTrayIcon, SIGNAL(activated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)), SLOT(SystemTrayMenuActivated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)));
    SystemTrayIcon.setIcon(QIcon("icon.png"));
    SystemTrayIcon.show();
    return Application.exec();
}
```

a context class that loads the qml and pops up the window -

```
#include "ApplicationContext.h"

#include <QQmlContext>

QApplicationContext::QApplicationContext()
{
    m_QmlApplicationEngine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("applicationContext", this);
    m_QmlApplicationEngine.load("QtRotationAnimationDemo.qml");
}

void QApplicationContext::SystemTrayMenuActivated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason eActivationReason)
{
    emit showWindow();
}
```

Seems like a bug to me, even though I agree that the life cycle of the window is kind of weird - it actually gets closed and then is shown again (but then again it responds to the signal so it eventually is alive).

I'll do some more debugging and possibly post a bug on Qt but if anyone has any relevant ideas, I'd be very thankful, since now all animations in my application on Windows are broken.

Comment: What version qt?

Comment: Instead of closing the window, can you use an onClosing handler (for the closing signal) to intercept and cancel the close event, and instead call hide()?

Comment: @MarkCh - I can reproduce this with both 5.8 / 5.9. Hiding shows the same behavior, while minimizing does not.